# iOS: ARC strong or weak reference with IBOutlets for nibs (for custom UITableviewCell)

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Sorry if this has been asked already but I've searched and haven't found an answer to the specific case I'm finding myself in right now.

I'm subclassing `UITableViewController`.  I don't have a custom nib for it.  I also have a custom `tableview` `cell` that I'm implementing that *does* have it's own custom nib.  When I'm creating the outlet for this cell should I be creating a weak reference?   Because it ends up as a subview of the `TableViewController` I would think yes but the Apple docs also note that  top level objects in a nib should be strong so I'm confused.  Any help would be appreicated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of the post above.

Comment: Because it's a custom nib for a tableview cell, and not for a UIViewController, I think this question has some merit and should not be closed.

Comment: Thanks Emile.  I posted because its *not* a dupe.  That question didnt ask exactly what I asked which is why I posted.

Comment: Aren't cells memory managed by the UITableView? I don't see why you would have an outlet for the cell in the controller. Subclass or no subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Use a weak reference. This is because when your view is unloaded, if it is weak the link will automatically be set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the cell in the `tableview` only outside of the `xib` (and I'm pretty sure you would be), then it needs to be a strong reference or else the cell will be released before you can use it in constructing the table.

Possibly if you made use of it in `viewDidLoad` it would still exist, but best not to rely on the call cycle acting in that way.

Comment: "If you put the cell in the tableview only outside of the xib (and I'm pretty sure you would be)".  I assume you mean programmatically.  I'm loading the UITableViewCell nib in the call to tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: where i'm configuring the cell as required.

Comment: That's pretty much what I meant.  If your reference is weak then the cell will be autoreleased before the code reaches that method (or I think it should be).

Answer (score 0):

> "Apple docs also note that top level objects in a nib should be strong so I'm confused"

This is true no matter what UIView subclass you're using. If you have a nib with a UITableViewCell and a UIView IBOutlet, both as top level objects, the UIView needs to be strong. if the UIView IBOutlet is a subview of your UITableViewCell in the nib, it should be weak.

Answer (score 0):

You must use weak ownership.Because your table view cell have a strong reference to it's parent view and your parent view have a strong reference to it's subviews

Like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyView *viewContainerSubview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topLevelView;
```