# Using ARC on iOS 4, do I need to nil my IBOutlet properties when using unsafe_unretained instead of weak?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, reference-counting

When using ARC with iOS 5, a weak IBOutlet creates a zeroing reference, avoiding the need to

```
self.< IBOutlet property > = nil;
```

in *-(void)viewDidUnload*

If I'm using iOS 4 (**and using ARC**) and forced to use ***unsafe_unretained*** instead, does it mean I have to override *viewDidUnload* and set the property to nil manually?

EDIT:
This relates to my case: [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc)
The exception being: I can't use the 'weak' keyword which creates the zeroing reference.

Hope my question is clearer.

Thanks

Comment: WHy are you using `unsafe_unretained`? In iOS (as opposed to OS X) IBOutlets should be retained.

Comment: @Zaph I've just had a look at the [Resource Programming Guide - Managing the Lifetimes of Objects from Nib Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) and it seems to suggest you only use strong for the top level objects and weak for everything else, which is contrary to what I used to believe but it makes sense with this line `Outlets that you create to, for example, subviews of a view controller’s view or a window controller’s window, are arbitrary references between objects that do not imply ownership.`.

Comment: @Paul I understand and what you say is true--but that advice is really only good for developers that fully understand all of the implications. Clearly this op doesn't and that applies to a great many developers. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ARC, as I am sure you have realized, the weak attribute cannot be used pre-iOS5. The other side of that coin would be to use unsafe_unretained. Weak attributes will automatically set your properties to nil. Unsafe_retained (aka "assign" in pre-iOS 5), will not, and you need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Without a property (in iOS) the IBOutlet will be ivar is set and retained by KVC. With a `@property` the ivar is set by setting the property.

On an ARC project, if one creates a nib and drags an item (say `UILabel`) to the .h file a strong `@property` will be added as well as in the .m file a line setting the property to nil will be added to the `viewDidUnload` method and a @synthesize statement for the property.

There are other ways to handle the retaining of `nib` `IBOutlets` that work and may even be better by some metric.

From the Apple document [Resource Programming Guide - Managing the Lifetimes of Objects from Nib Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html):

> Because the behavior of outlets depends on the platform, the actual
>   declaration differs:
>
> For iOS, you should use:
>   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UserInterfaceElementClass *anOutlet;
>
> For OS X, you should use:
>   @property (assign) IBOutlet UserInterfaceElementClass *anOutlet;

My belief is to not fight the way Apple does things, doing so tends to make things harder. Also consider that Apple has inside information of the future of the platform. :-)

Comment: You are quoting from the Legacy section. I AM using ARC but with only 1 restriction due to using iOS 4 - I can't use the weak keyword (but can use strong). As such, my case relates to a non-legacy situation.

Comment: I've edited my question to include "using iOS 4 (and using ARC)"