# Difference between Strong and Weak IBOutlets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

What is the difference between `strong` and `weak` IBOutlets in the Xcode iOS 5.1 SDK?

I was previously using the 4.3 SDK, where strong IBOutlets did not exist. In addition, (auto)release is not available in the iOS 5.1 SDK.

Comment: You can't compare strong and nonatomic. I think you mean the difference between strong and weak. Have you tried to read something about it in the Apple docs?

Comment: @dasdom ok weak and strong reference differences guided me or any document link

Comment: Autorelease and release are available in iOS 5 if you disable ARC.  ARC is a feature that can be enabled or disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Strong` means that as long as this property points to an object, that object will not be automatically released. In non-ARC it's a synonym for `retain`

> Specifies that there is a strong (owning) relationship to the
>   destination object.

`Weak` instead, means that the object the property points to, is free to release but only if it sets the property to NULL. In ARC you use weak to ensure you do not own the object it points to

> Specifies that there is a weak (non-owning) relationship to the
>   destination object. If the destination object is deallocated, the
>   property value is automatically set to nil.

`Nonatomic` means that if multiple threads try to read or to change the property at once, badness can happen. Consequences are that there will be partially-written values or over-released objects = CRASH.

Take also a look [here, at Apple's documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

From there, examples are

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet MyView *viewContainerSubview;
@property (strong) IBOutlet MyOtherClass *topLevelObject;
```

Check also [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1) to know more about `strong` and `weak`.

Comment: Weak isn't what you say it is.

Answer (score 2):

In ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) `Strong` tells the compiler that the property-owner relationship is "strong".  It is equivalent to `retain` in the autorelease pool memory scheme.   Apple has a article on transitioning to ARC [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

The property which you declare as a strong , it owns the object and the compiler will take care that which any object assigns this property. This property will destroyed when we set to nil.

When you don't want the control life time then u declare as a week property.