# IBOutlet for NSTextView in a ARC project

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, nstextview, iboutlet, weak

As you read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469) in most cases a `IBOutlet` should be weak.

Now as you can read in the [development library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6) not all classes support weak references.
(e.g.  NSTextView). This means you have to use assign:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
```

If you use a weak reference you will get the following error:
"Synthesis of a weak-unavailable property is disallowed because it requires synthesis of an ivar of the __weak object"

What the documentation missed to mention is now you have to set the property again to nil after it's usage e.g. by a `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.textView = nil;
}
```

As far as I understood classes marked with `NS_AUTOMATED_REFCOUNT_WEAK_UNAVAILABLE` don't support weak references but what is the reason?

Comment: As per linked post `IBOutlets` should be **strong** by default!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I found the reason why some classes don't support a weak reference:

As you can read [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.restrictions.weak):

Rationale: historically, it has been possible for a class to provide its own reference-count implementation by overriding retain, release, etc. However, weak references to an object require coordination with its class's reference-count implementation because, among other things, weak loads and stores must be atomic with respect to the final release. Therefore, existing custom reference-count implementations will generally not support weak references without additional effort. This is unavoidable without breaking binary compatibility.