# Why cannot NSTextView for a weak reference?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I noticed than in OSX, the `NSTextView` cannot for a weak refference (if you try to link it weak, you will get)

```
Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x600000122da0) of class NSTextView. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.
```

also the outlet from XCode is created as assign by default

Why there cannot be a weak reference? What can be the reason?

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882710/iboutlet-for-nstextview-in-a-arc-project) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Check FAQ here [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226):

> Q:Which classes don’t support weak references?
>
> A:You cannot currently create weak references to instances of the
>   following classes: NSATSTypesetter, NSColorSpace, NSFont, NSMenuView,
>   NSParagraphStyle, NSSimpleHorizontalTypesetter, and NSTextView.
>
> etc.

Comment: So what is the solution? How can you break retain cycles with NSTextField in Swift?

Answer (score -2):

Read the message carefully. Read past the word NSTextView. It tells you *exactly* why at this moment you cannot create a weak reference to the NSTextView. You just have to read it.

For example, while dealloc is running, you cannot create new weak references anymore because the object will be going away and all weak references will be set to nil. Trying to assign the object to a weak variable will keep that variable nil, even though the object is not nil (yet).

And this has nothing to do with NSTextView.

Comment: thats not correct, the problem is that NSTextView uses it's own reference counting and therefore cannot be used with weak reference