# Create UICollectionViewCell subclass with xib

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass with linked a xib, I have do this:
I have create a new xib file and I have add a `UICollectionViewCell` in it, then I have create this subclass file:

```
@interface MyCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end
```

Also I have linked in the file owner custom class the `MyCell` class in interface builder, and I have added a `UILabel`, then in my `UICollectionView` viewDidLoad I do this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

As well as in this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.label.text = @"Cell Text";


return cell;
}
```

However this doesn't work, I receive this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x907eca0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.'
```

What did I do wrong? How can I connect a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass to a xib, and display it in a `UICollectionView`?

EDIT:

i have do this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *identifier = @"MyCell";

static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

if(!nibMyCellloaded)
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle: nil];
    [cv registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
    nibMyCellloaded = YES;
}

MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.labelCell.text = @"Text";


return cell;
}
```

Comment: so in the case of using a xib with a connected class, it seems you have to call collectionView register on both the nib file and the class you linked with the xib? is your workflow invoking the cell class' initWithFrame initializer?

Comment: Your "edited code" is buggy. Static variables inside a member function are shared by all instances. If you have multiple view controller instances, only the first one will call `registerNib`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Make sure the cell on the .xib file know what's the type of the cell.

Select the cell on your interface builder

[image]

and then on the identity inspector

[image]

Subsequently associate your labels with your properties. (I think you already did that)

Then I'd recommend to verify if you already loaded the .xib file on your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method

```
NSString *identifier = @"MyCell";    

    static BOOL nibMyCellloaded = NO;

    if(!nibMyCellloaded)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle: nil];
        [cv registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier];
        nibMyCellloaded = YES;
    }
```

Comment: i have edited my question...take a look please...

Comment: no i'm sorry, i have enlarge the cell and know works...

Comment: can't you just call the registerNib once on viewDidLoad instead of doing the check every time the collection view is asking for a cell?

Comment: Using `static` is a bad practice. The static variable is shared for all instances. The second view controller of the same class will not load the .xib file because `nibMyCellloaded`  will be set to `YES`  by the first one.

Comment: Important note here is that .XIB File's Owner should  NOT be set to MyCell, but only the root element Class. Otherwise the solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 21):

You can find the answer in this document [UICollectionView adding UICollectionCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184968/uicollectionview-adding-uicollectioncell).

> Only UICollectionView inside StoryBoard have UICollectionViewCell inside. If use XIB, create a new XIB with CellName.xib, add CollectionViewCell to it, specify name of UICollectionView custom class. After that use registerNib.Sample code: https://github.com/lequysang/TestCollectionViewWithXIB

Comment: Thanks. your code is the only one that worked for me. I'm just wondering why use make the `UILabel` property of cell `weak`? I thought all IBOutlets must be `strong`.

Comment: @Ali regarding your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729141/351810