# Subclassing a custom collection view cell created from a nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, xib, uicollectionviewcell

I am struggling to figure out how to subclass a custom collection view cell that was created with a nib.

Here is my setup:

I have a custom collection view cell that is the superclass for all other collection view cells in my app, this view was created with a nib file.

Now I want to subclass the custom collection view cell, and add more things again with a nib file.

How do I subclass a cell created with a nib file?

****I need to subclass a nib file and add to it with a nib file.*******

Thank you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create UICollectionViewCell subclass with xib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466959/create-uicollectionviewcell-subclass-with-xib)

Comment: I want to subclass a cell made with a xib. This is not the same question.