# Adding UICollectionView to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview

All,

I am adding a UICollectionView to a UIView but it's failing to load cells because it seems that this:

```
[self.buttonsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AccountMenuCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AccountMenuCell"];
```

Is getting loaded after it hits the delegates for the UICollectionView. Normally this would be placed in viewDidLoad but is not available in a UIView.

```
- (AccountMenuCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     AccountMenuCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AccountMenuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    [cell.accountMenuButton setTitle:@"Deposit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     return cell;

 }
```

Any guidance?

EDIT:

So I am using a view from the storyboard initially and then adding a subview which is Account Menu. Within this view I have a Collection View.

Comment: take this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466959/create-uicollectionviewcell-subclass-with-xib else use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically and finally try this http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. When people ask for more details, go back and edit your question to make it clearer. This is especially important with code, since code is all but unreadable in the form it's displayed in a comment.

Comment: You need to add a lot more background information (to your original question). Are you using storyboards or XIB files to create this view? (view controller?) Or are you creating it with code? Explain the life cycle of your collection view in detail.

Comment: Yeah I read those Anbu, the problem is - it's hitting the collection view delegates before loading the registerNib line. As normally this would sit in viewDidLoad but I am in a UIView with this not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with the default method and instantiate your Cell inside of the cellForItem...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
AccountMenuCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AccountMenuCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.accountMenuButton setTitle:@"Deposit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
return cell;
}
```

and .. verify with Breakpoints if your code is running..

Comment: Tried this and it crashes prior to hitting this code.