# How can we load .xib files in collection view cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created collection view programmatically and I am adding .xib file in collection view cell like below

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"CollectionCell";

    CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollectionCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.itemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[indexPath.row]];
    cell.itemLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item Index %ld",(long)indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

But it's showing exception like

```
could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CollectionCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

What did I do here wrong??? Help me please.

Comment: You need to register the CollectionCell class before dequeueing

Comment: when you allocate this collection view, did you do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466959/create-uicollectionviewcell-subclass-with-xib

Comment: that stack overflow post didn't have registering xibs i apologize, but i don't think it will help you D: maybe i should just go copy paste the function for simplicities sake

Comment: [<collection view> registerClass:<collection view subclass class> forCellWithReuseIdentifier:<reuse identifier string>];

Comment: how to register can you post related code