# Loading a view from NIB, IBOutletCollection is nil even though other IBOutlet's are working fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I laid out a view in a NIB file, then added my UIView subclass as the file owner.

The subclass looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *images;
```

The properties are weak because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7729141/1016515

Then I wired up the label and the UIImageViews in the nib, from the view to the file owner.

Then, in the awakeFromNib part of the subclass, I did this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryButton" owner:self options:nil];
NSLog(@"label: %@",self.categoryLabel);
NSLog(@"images: %@",self.images);
```

I expected to see the addresses of the categoryLabel and the images. Instead I found that the category label was fine and the images are `nil`.

This is quite puzzling, because the declarations for `images` and `categoryLabel` are identical. Why does one work and the other fail?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I'm putting this up because I didn't find the question anywhere, but it seems like a pretty easy mistake to make if you're used to working with IBOutlets but not IBOutletCollections.

I made the properties `weak` because that's what I usually do for IBOutlets for the reasons discussed in another question.

What I neglected to realize is that the IBOutletCollection is an instance variable of the class, not just an arbitrary reference into the view hierarchy. Therefore, if it is a weak property the `NSArray *` will immediately be released because the view hierarchy isn't retaining it as it does for other IBOutlet properties.

The fix is simple, make the property `strong`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *images;
```

**Update**: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31395938/1016515), almost all IBOutlets should be strong, unless they must be weak to avoid a retain cycle. This is new, and most documentation still says outlets should be weak.

Comment: Works. Easy to miss this. Thought of same way yo idid!

Comment: Missed it too because being weak, it automatically nils out and doesn't crash with a forin (foreach, whatever)