# When should I use Strong vs Weak for IBOutlets (further clarification)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, iboutlet

I thought I understood it clearly from this question --> [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc) but I recently had a discussion which left me totally confused. Can someone just confirm if the following is correct? (if this is a duplicate I didn't mean to break any rules.. just need clarification as I can understand diagrams better than words..)

[image]

Under ARC (MacOSx)

1. view1 = strong
2. MainView = weak   (In WindowControllerA)
3. MainView = strong (In ViewControllerB)
4. view2 = strong
5. view3 = weak (In ViewcontrollerB)
6. view3 = strong (In ViewControllerC)

If this is correct then can someone confirm please..

In the diagram above, we have a windowControllerA that is **on the screen**. In windowControllerA's view, there are 2 NSViews. view1 belongs to the windowController, but mainView belongs to the view of the instianciated viewController, ViewControllerB.

ViewControllerB also contains 2 views within its mainView. View2 is owned by viewControllerB while view3 belongs to another instanced viewController, ViewControllerC.

ViewController C has one view which it owns.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most outlets for subviews don't need to be strong references because, after all, they're subviews loaded as part of a view hierarchy. As long as the top-level view exists, and as long as you don't go removing the subviews from their parents, the subviews in the view hierarchy will be retained by their parents for the lifetime of the top-level view.

In the days before ARC, some people were happy to rely on the view hierarchy to retain their views for them and so set their outlet properties to `assign`. Others didn't like the idea that a hiccup in the view hierarchy could leave them with a handful of dangling pointers, and so set their properties to `retain`. ARC gives us zeroing weak references, so that your outlets will be set to `nil` if the objects they point to are deallocated, and that makes using weak references for outlets seem a lot safer. On the other hand, if you want to maintain a reference to a view even if the view hierarchy that contains is is deallocated, you should set that reference to `strong`.

Since your view controller is responsible for the view hierarchy it manages (i.e. "owns"), it should have a strong reference to the top-level view. You don't need to worry too much about this, as the `view` property of any UIViewController-derived view controller is set to `retain` (i.e. `strong`).

Comment: Hi Caleb, so in the diagram above.. which should be strong/weak? I dont really want to "not worry about it" as i wish to understand it. Do i just make top level objects **strong** and make every thing else **weak**?

Comment: @Jai I said you "don't need to worry" because the `view` property of UIViewController is already strong. In other words, you don't need to do anything special to make it happen. As I said above, outlets for subviews can be weak *unless* you want to hang onto a view even if the rest of the view graph is deallocated. I can't quite grok your diagram, so won't comment on that.

Comment: @Caleb So if an IBOutlet is set to strong, it will remain in memory. But how do we get access to this memory?

Answer (score 2):

As long as I understood this "All the top-level objects should be strong. And subviews should be weak". So in that case **view2 should be weak also**

- view1 = strong
- MainView = weak (In WindowControllerA)
- MainView = strong (In ViewControllerB)
- view2 = weak (since mainview already hold it)
- view3 = weak (In ViewcontrollerB)
- view3 = strong (In ViewControllerC)

Comment: thanks. +1. Based on the question i asked above, your answer is correct. but i decided to change the setup and went with the answer below as its more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

So many discussions about the weak vs. strong reference to .xib objects in the File Owner's IBOutlets --- and it seems EVERYONE is only concerned about views and subviews.

Subviews are owned by their superviews, and so as long as you do not tear down view hierarchy programmatically (and take responsibility for view ownership while at it) you don't need to worry too much.

BUT --- what about all those other objects you create in .xibs regularly, like NSArrayControllers and those root-level UI items that are NOT views, like Windows, Panels, Alerts, and so on --- should THEY be referenced strong? weak?

I really need some low level explanation of how xibs work. When an object is a "File's owner" and loads its nib file, What gets loaded and initialized? Just objects to which you have IBOutlets? Every top-level object?

Who owns all these root-level objects? After all the controller who loads the nib (and is normally the "File's Owner" owns the .xib --- but does this mean it owns (automatically) the root level objects in the nib?

If so --- what is the difference if you have a weak IBOutlet reference to a .xib object, or strong, or none at all ---- you're still "File's Owner" for that object,

Some better explanation will do.

Comment: Array controllers etc. should be strong. The point is that outlets to elements in XIB need to be strong, unless they are a part of a view hierarchy and are held by their superview / parent window, but it just happens that most elements you link to are, so as a result only unrelated objects from a XIB like other controllers need to be strong.

Comment: When you load a NIB, all the elements on the diagram are loaded into memory, but if they aren't retained by anything then they will be released immediately. Controls in a view/window are retained by their parents, but independent elements must be retained using a strong IBOutlet.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. Still, in the old days, when we did not have "properties" and everyone used plain members of their controllers as IBOutlets, I can't recall ever retaining any IBOutlet members in my "awakeFromNib" etc. who owned the top level NIB objects then?