# Which way of declaring IBoutlet is better

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering which way is prefer for declaring an IBOutlet in a subview?

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView  *mTableView;
```

or

```
  IBOutlet UITableView  *mTableView;
```

I believe the first one is better, but not too sure.

Comment: I guess, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729141/3532040

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the better. Consider this : If you use the assistance editor and you Ctrl + Drag a view item straight into the code file, it will add it exactly like that

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView  *mTableView;
```