# Insert margin between navigation bar and UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am developing iOS App with UITableView. I begin to develop the App with Master-Detail Application and I use StoryBoard.

I would like to insert 320px*100px margin between navigation bar and UITableView.
(Height of navigation bar is 44px.)

I am writing down the following code. However margin doesn't appear.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
@interface MasterViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 144, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: You are setting your tableView frame to origin (0,44) size (320,100).  Don't you want origin (0,144) to give you the gap?  If so, try `CGRectMake(0,144,320,self.tableView.frame.size.height-100)`

Comment: As you indicated, the value of CGRectMake was wrong and edited to the correct value in the above code. However It remains that margin doesn't appear.

Comment: `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` is better to use `weak` for `IBOutlet` outlets, link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc

Comment: I change to weak, however no change.

Comment: Try setting `contentInset` for tableview, `[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)];`

Comment: Thank you very much. I can insert margin with [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)].

Answer (score 2):

This your line:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 100);
```

100 sets `tableView` height to 100 instead of margin. Try following please:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44 + 100, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 44 - 100);
```

Comment: Thank you. However margin doesn't appear.

Comment: Don't you change tableView.frame in other methods?

Comment: No I don't change in other methods.

Comment: please try to change bg color of related views. For example,     `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];`
`self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`. Just to see better how it looks

Comment: the screenshot is very appreciated

Comment: Only when I pull down the table, red color appears between navigation bar and the table. Except this case, both red and blue don't appear.

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout in your xib file? Please try to comment the line we discussed and set the same frame in xib (if you use AutoLayout - make sure you are correcting the constraints properly)

Comment: Thank you very much. I can insert margin with [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0)].