# Objective C: GestureRecognizer in ViewController --> retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following property defined in the header file of one of my ViewControllers (VC):

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *articleImageView1;
```

In the implementation of the VC, in the method `viewDidLoad`, I attach TapRecognizers to these properties:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *captureImage1TapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                      initWithTarget:self
[self.articleImageView1 addGestureRecognizer:captureImage1TapRecognizer];
```

The VC holds strongly the `UIImageView`.

1. Does this `UIImageView` also contain the VC strongly through the GestureRecognizer?
2. Is this then a classical example of a retain cycle?
3. If so, would this be correct solution?

   ```
   -(void)viewDidUnload {
        ...
       [self setArticleImageView1:nil];
        ...
       [super viewDidUnload];
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

From [Concepts of Obj-C programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html) on target - action pattern:

> Control objects do not (and should not) retain their targets

Thus `UIGestureRecognizer` does not retain VC and there is no retain cycle.

**Additional remarks**

As pointed out by skyddict, `-viewDidUnload` has been deprecated and you should use `-dealloc` to perform cleanup. However, you don't need to `nil` your properties - they are released when object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all `IBOutlet` properties should be declared as `weak` and not `retain`. Secondly, `viewDidUnload` has been deprecated since iOS 6.0. You should use `dealloc` in order to do the final cleanup for any `NSObject` subclass (you override this method to dispose of resources other than the object’s instance variables).

If you have the image view declared as `weak`, there won't be any retain cycles.You don't have to retain the `IBOutlet` (since it's already retained by it's superview).  If you make `IBOutlet`s weak, you won't have to nil them out as you point out.

Comment: Makes sense. I instantly changed all my IBOutlets in the header file to `weak`, instead of `strong`/`retain`. However, now the app freezes when I open the `View` associated with the `ViewController`. Is there something special I should pay attention to?

Comment: Post a gist of your ViewController.m and .h

Comment: Setting `IBOutlet` properties as `strong` doesn't cause retain cycles by itself. From memory management point it usually makes no difference whether they are  `strong` or `weak` - sometimes you even need them strong (if linked view is not initially in the view hierarchy). Also, there is no need to `nil` them - they are just setters and getters to instance variables and they are released automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a strong reference cycle here. This is a solution that should work just fine.

The view controller has a strong reference to the `UIImageView`. The `UIImageView` holds its gesture recognizers in an array (strong reference as well), but the gesture recognizer does not hold target/action or delegate strongly.

You may hold onto the `UIImageView` via a weak reference, but since iOS 6 views are not unloaded anymore, so it won't make any difference for memory management.