# When to use Strong and When to use Weak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, xcode6, automatic-ref-counting

Well I have Just started digging about memory management concepts in iOS.

I know what are strong , weak , assign ... so on.

But  I am confused in two things:

1. When should I use Strong and When I use Weak
2. When using weak will create problem.

Suppose I have a Class.

```
ViewController.h

  @property (weak) NSString *myString;
```

Now I want to know whether at some point it will create any problem ? If Yes then How and when ?

Comment: I am not asking about the difference between them.. That I know..I want to know the practical use and effects that is clear from my question i think @jlehr

Comment: i am not sure but i use weak for all my outlets!!!

Comment: yes thats the point...I want the reason if I use strong what happens,,,

Comment: @user5214391 While the dupe says this: "subviews/controls of a view controller's main view because those views are already strongly held by the main view." a better answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc Generally you use weak to prevent a retain cycle. Apple used to recommend weak outlets but now they are recommending strong outlets and are updating their documentation. So use a strong outlet unless the view you are retaining retains something higher in the hierarchy than itself as that could result in a retain cycle.