# Xcode 7 : image view created in IB is not being allocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

< SOLVED >

I created my project using **Xcode 6**. I had such a piece of code there:

**.h file:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView7;
```

**.m file:**

```
self.featureViews = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView1];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView2];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView3];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView4];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView5];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView6];
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView7];
```

All image views were created using the interface builder and everything worked fine.

But recently I updated to **Xcode 7**, and I had a necessity to add one more `UIImageView`.

I did totally *the same thing*: created the imageView8 in IB, created a new referencing outlet and added the following string

```
[self.featureViews addObject:self.imageView8];
```

To my great astonishment now the app falls with the **-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil** error when adding imageView8.

```
2015-09-22 16:20:13.063 XXX[1752:38656] **Image view 7 <UIImageView: 0x7f8396bd2e40; frame = (251 6; 33 33); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f8396bd2fe0>>**
2015-09-22 16:20:13.064 XXX[1752:38656] **Image view 8 (null)**
```

Does anyone have any idea why this may happen?

**Update**

I just simply had to reset the iOS simulator and perform a full build to solve the problem...

Comment: in Xcode 7 you need to set all IBOutlet to strong ownership qualifier.

Comment: Did you connect the outlets? Also, you could use an `IBOutletCollection`

Comment: @AshishP That's definitely not true.

Comment: Also you can use IBOutleCollection in such cases http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/

Comment: plz check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc what apple engineer said in session from WWDC 2015

Comment: Yes, all outlets are connected.

Comment: Using IBOutletCollection seems to be reasonable, but it's written the order is not guaranteed there, which is critical in my case

Comment: Changing properties to strong did not make any affect

Comment: The error indicates that imageView8 is null. If it is properly connected, as you seem to think, then first step would be to delete the app on the simulator/device and then do a full build and run to make sure it is not a deployment glitch. If that fails, then I would recheck your connections.

Comment: Thanks Rory, resetting and rebuilding did work. I just never thought that such things may happen because of a deployment glitch

Comment: Excellent. Sadly it happens a lot. You would hope newer versions of xcode would have fixed this. Sometimes a build clean/rebuild is enough, but often it needs the app deleted.