# Clear the content of UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` and a `UIButton` in my app and I'm trying to get the text content of the `UITextView` to be cleared when the `UIButton` is tapped.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

@IBAction func ClearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // I want to clear the text content of textView
    }
```

Is there **built-in** function for that, in the `UITextView` class? I didn't find anything when I searched the `UITextView` class in Xcode.

My app is on Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2.

Comment: Why downvotes? What’s wrong with the question?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the down votes. As an extra check, can we assume you've connected your outlets correctly in Interface Builder? The other answers given by others below are good suggestions to clearing text. By the way, I believe your UITextView outlet should be strongly referenced not weakly referenced according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc

Comment: @Zhang Why I should use Strong rather than Weak? There was a lot of opinions in the link you posted and Xcode uses Weak for default.

Comment: Well, numerous people have cited Apple engineers recommending to use strong, one even mentioned performance benefits. As long as your app is working, whatever floats the boat I guess. I myself like to think of buttons defined inside a UIViewController as belonging to that controller, forming a single self contained coherent unit, so I maintain a strong reference to it. The thought of something weakly attached to my UIViewController feels like it's dangling on, gives me an uncomfortable feeling metaphorically speaking.

Comment: @Zhang Ok, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a ready function to clear the text content of an `UITextView` so I created this code to do that:

The `UITextView` variable:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
```

Function to clear the `UITextView`:

```
@IBAction func ClearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        textView.selectAll(textView)
        if let range = textView.selectedTextRange { textView.replace(range, withText: "") }
    }
```

When the clear-button is tapped, the function checks is there any text in the `UITextView` and if there is some, it will select all the text in the `UITextView` and replace it with an empty `String`.

**EDIT**:

There is also the simple way to do it, which, for some reason, didn't work when I tried it before (probably because the bugs in Xcode 10.1), **but this way the user can't undo it, if they accidentally tap the clear button**:

```
@IBAction func ClearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   textView.text = ""
}
```

Or with extension:

```
extension UITextView {
    func clear() {
        self.text = ""
    }
}
```

Call `textView.clear()` when you want to clear the text.

Comment: Why not `textView.text = ""` ?

Comment: Do you mean to clear a portion/selected or all the content ?

Comment: All the content

Comment: This only `@IBAction func ClearButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) { textView.text = "" }` doesn't work ?

Comment: Now it works. Strange, because it didn't do anything when I tried it before. Maybe the problem was in Xcode; when I have renamed some variables and functions before, it haven't always change the names in everywhere in my project.

Comment: It's more likely that it was an error on your part than an Xcode bug...

Comment: Maybe, but Xcode have shown lot of weird errors lately in my projects, even there haven't been anything wrong in my code and they have disappeared after I have builded the app few times

Answer (score 3):

Small improvement:

`textView.text = nil`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `textView.text = ""`. If that's not working it could be that you're using a placeholder. Try `textView.placeholder = ""`